# Make Evolution go through a SOCKS proxy

Tags: linux, ssh, gnome, proxy, evolution

I use Evolution for email when I'm on [Linux](http://www.linuxmint.com/). Most of the apps follow with GNOME's proxy setting, but Evolution does not do SOCKS proxies.

Right now my proxy is simple SSH forwarding. The SOCKS host is localhost with a special port, and a background SSH process takes care of the rest.

My question is:

- Is this the best way to handle this?
- Is there a way I can get Evolution to work with my proxy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://www.ubuntux.org/evolution-using-a-socks-proxy) entry refers to using [Tsocks](http://tsocks.sourceforge.net/) to bypass the limitation. From what I understand Evolution only supports SOCKS on HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked whether anything has actually changed since 2009, but for me it seems to work to go to Edit -> Preferences (Ctrl+Shift+S) -> Network and enter a SOCKS proxy there.  Noticeably, it seems to tunnel my IMAPS and SMTPS connections just fine.

[image: Evolution network settings]